# Jquery selector: whenever a user clicks on the Category 1/2/3, its `<ul>` will be visible

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got the following structure: - nested UL

```
<ul>
<li>Category 1
    <ul>
        <li> Category 1.1</li>
        <li> Category 1.2</li>
        <li> Category 1.3</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li> Category 2
    <ul>
        <li>Category 2.1</li>
        <li>Category 2.2</li>
        <li>Category 2.3</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>Category 3
    <ul>
        <li>Category 3.1</li>
        <li>Category 3.2</li>
        <li>Category 3.3</li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

I've applied a rule with CSS:

```
ul{
    list-style: none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
ul ul{
    display:none;
}
```

which leaves only the MAIN category shown.

What i was trying to do is, whenever a user clicks on the Category 1/2/3, its `<ul>` will be visible. I've tried this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("ul li").click(function() {
        $(this + "ul").Slidedown(800);
    });

});
```

well, basically I was trying to select the `<ul` element that was inside the main `<ul>`.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("ul li").click(function() {
        $(this).find('ul').Slidedown(800);
    });

});
```

Given your selector, click on `Category 1.1` will also call the callback, but it won't do anything since it doesn't have any `ul` tags. Still, it's better to add a `class` and bind the event only on those.

Comment: Works perfectly, just not the function slidedown().

If I want to achieve the scroll down effect, I'm using the show() function ATM, any idea who slidedown() isnt working?

Comment: @kfirba Because it is `slideDown`, take a look @Rocket answer.

Answer (score 1):

something like this should work

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("ul > li").click(function() {
        $(this).find("> ul").Slidedown(800);
    });

});
```

Although, an even more efficient approach(thanks to Ian) would be:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("ul").children('li').click(function() {
        $(this).children("ul").Slidedown(800);
    });

});
```

using the  '>' operator tells jquery to only look for direct children, if you don't use '>' the code will apply to the li elements inside the nested ul as well.  also, read the other answers info about using 'this' properly.

Comment: If you want to target children, use `.children()` and not `.find()`

Comment: @Ian yeah, thats a better way of doing things.  I'll be editing my answer and using that approach from now on. :)

Answer (score 1):

`this` is not a string, it's a DOM element.

Instead of `$(this + "ul")`, you want `$('ul', this)`.

P.S. `.Slidedown` should be `.slideDown`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(this).find('ul:hidden').slideDown(800);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're concatenating the DOM element with `"ul"` to a string - that's not a valid selector. Instead, use [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to apply the `ul` selector in the context of the current element.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("ul li").click(function() {
        $(this).find('ul').Slidedown(800);
    });
});
```

And maybe make the `ul li` selector a bit more specific to match only the outer list items.